# How to Install Shodan CLI into Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-shell, shodan

I'm unable to use Shodan CLI.

## Steps:

I have tried to follow the steps here: [Shodan CLI - Official Page](https://cli.shodan.io/)

Even by running:

```
easy_install shodan
```

I have also tried to:

```
pip install shodan
```

And it does install but it still don't works, the thing is that I get the following warning error:

```
WARNING: The script shodan is installed in '/home/USER/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I'm still not able to make it work. Not even by going to the Directory `/home/USER/.local/bin`

### PD:

I have even tried to:

```
apt-get install shodan
```

But there is no package found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your directory to `PATH` directory by typing in the command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
```

or

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/USER/.local/bin
```

You can also use `alias` as another option:

```
alias shodan='./.local/bin/shodan'
```

Check if `shodan`'s directory is listed by typing:

```
alias shodan
```

The directory should appear like this:

```
alias shodan='./.local/bin/shodan'
```

Either of these methods successfully runs `shodan` on my end.

I've used the following links as references:

- [Warning "not on PATH" when I tried to install python extensions. I'm new to Linux -- what does this mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612779/warning-not-on-path-when-i-tried-to-install-python-extensions-im-new-to-linu)
- [In ubuntu 20.04, how to fix pip path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242234/in-ubuntu-20-04-how-to-fix-pip-path)
- [How do I correct the path for pip?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187701/how-do-i-correct-the-path-for-pip)